# Remote Powershell Access Denied

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a SQL Server database with some tables and a trigger, the trigger would create either FolderA on ServerA or FolderB on ServerB, this is the command I pass in the trigger for ServerA:

```
SET @folder = 'powershell.exe  invoke-command -computername ServerA { powershell.exe  -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass  -File C:\FolderScript\FolderA.ps1 "' +@folderName+'" }'

EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @folder
```

I have an intermittent issues with it, it will work just fine for couple of days before it stops then I would have to run it manually from PS on ServerA.

Because it's intermittent, then we can rule out firewall, permissions, PowerShell enable remote. I have a web based application (asp.net) that users run from their machines and it connect to the SQL Server database where the trigger is located.

Is there some sort of sessions that needs to stay open to prevent access denied error? I can't think of anything else that might cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is with your quoting happening in the command:

```
SET @folder = 'powershell.exe -Command "Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerA { & ''C:\FolderScript\FolderA.ps1'' ' + @folderName + ' }"'
```

This should be sufficient to resolve your issue.  You do not need to repeatedly call `powershell.exe` as you can natively call scripts with the call operator (`&`).

Comment: I am going to try your solutions and see, the thing is every-time I change something in the script, it will start working for few days before it decides to stop working....

Comment: Without more detail about your exception messages it's impossible to say definitively @netasp

Comment: this is the error message I will usually get after few days of working without issues: [ServerA ] Connecting to remote server ServerA  failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (ServerA :String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken

Comment: @netasp Is it possible whatever service account you're using doesn't have access or is being locked out?

Comment: the user account that runs the trigger is in the Administrators group and a local system administrator, usually with permissions either you can access it or you can not access it...its very simple and that is why it's so frustrating as I don't understand how can it work for 3 days or a week even then it decides to not to?

Comment: @netasp It might be an unfortunate case of a kerberos ticket expiring?  I don't have more knowledge to help you further unfortunately

Comment: It's like when a trigger defined in MS SQL Database gets executed/run, who is running it? is it the SQL agent or some other process/service?

Comment: @netasp It should be whatever account you set up the instance services to run as (whether that's NETWORK SERVICE, SYSTEM, etc. is up to however it was configured)